# Digitar em um input e gerar uma sigla no segundo input com 3 caracteres

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Olá! Preciso de ajuda!! Gostaria de criar uma sigla para o cliente com 3 caracteres, quando digito no primeiro input vai gerando no segundo input, exemplos: "**ABO**BORA" gera "**ABO**", "**AB**OBORA **D**OURADA" gera "**ABD**", "**A**BOBORA **D**OURADA **B**ONITA" gera "**ADB**".

**Tenho:**

```
<input type="text" name="nomeCliente" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('nomeCliente'); ?>" class="form-control text-uppercase nomeSigla" id="nomeCliente" />

<input type="text" minlength="3" maxlength="3" name="siglaCliente" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('siglaCliente'); ?>" class="form-control text-uppercase siglaSigla" id="siglaCliente" />
```

Gostaria de pegar os dados pela **class** para utilizar em outros formulários (Contatos, fornecedores, etc).

Tentei iniciar os testes usando esse código, mas apenas faz a cópia para o próximo input e nem limita o segundo a 3 caracteres.

```
$(".nomeSigla").on('input',function(event) {
   var data=$(this).val();
   $(".siglaSigla").val(data);
```

});

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente eu criei dois `input`s:

```html
<input type="text" class="full-text" placeholder="Texto completo">
<input type="text" class="short-text" placeholder="Texto abreviado">
```

E agora o código Javascript (não está super otimizado, mas está funcionando):

```js
$('.full-text').keyup((event) => {
  const text = event.target.value

  // Verifica se o input .full-text possui algum espaço em branco
  if (hasWhiteSpace(text)) {
    const separatedText = text.split(" ")
    const firstWord = separatedText[0]
    const secondWord = separatedText[1]
    const thirdWord = separatedText[2]

    // Caso o usuário só tenha digitado duas palavras, pegue as duas primeiras letras da primeira palavra e a última letra da terceira
    if (!thirdWord) {
      $('.short-text').val(getFirstTwoLetters(firstWord) + getFirstLetter(secondWord))
    // Caso não, pegue a primeira letra de cada uma das palavras
    } else {
      $('.short-text').val(getFirstLetter(firstWord) + getFirstLetter(secondWord) + getFirstLetter(thirdWord))
    }
  } else {
    // Caso o usuario só tenha digitado uma palavra, pegue as três primeiras letras desta palavra
    $('.short-text').val(getFirstThreeLetters(text))
  }
})

const getFirstLetter = s => {
  if (!s) return '';

  return s.charAt(0)
}

const getFirstTwoLetters = s => {
  return s.substring(0, 2)
}

const getFirstThreeLetters = s => {
  return s.substring(0, 3)
}

const hasWhiteSpace = (s) => {
  return s.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
}
```

Aqui está o código funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/sj1an9yf/9/

P.S.: pode acontecer de o usuário digitar o seguinte: "A  " (a letra "A"  e dois espaços vazios), por isto aconselho remover os espaços vazios desta string antes de salvar no BD.

Comment: Robson! Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente! Vou remover os espaços para garantir

Comment: @LucianoMarangoni Ótimo! Por favor, aceite minha implementação como resposta entao.